# How to make import excel on ReactJS by tools 'read-excel-file'?

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, import

I'm a beginner. I think have something is wrong. I try to solve but not work.
I bring this code from HTML example. 
Please help me to know : how to write it in reactJS file.
Thank you very much.

```
import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        const input = document.getElementById('file');


        input.addEventListener('change', () => {
        readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then((data) => {
            document.getElementById('dtable').innerHTML = '<table border=1>' + data.map(row => '<tr>' + row.map(cell => `<td>${cell === null ? '' : cell}</td>`).join('') + '</tr>').join('') + '</table>';
        })
        })

    }



    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="file" id="file" />
                <div id="dtable"></div>
            </div>

        ); 

    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with this using xlsx to read excel file sheets. Just do something like this:

```
    import excel from 'xlsx';
    let fileName = "newData.xlsx";
    let workbook = excel.readFile(fileName);
    console.log(workbook) //should print an array with the excel file data
```

assuming a spreadsheet with name 'newData.xlsx' in your root folder. Then its just a matter of figuring out how to access the data you want. This should also be helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Can you make this by import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file';  at https://github.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file ?   I have request at company like this.

Comment: But Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this did work for me.
it is the very basic version - just to test the setup and reading..

`myproject/src/components/MyExcelImport/index.jsx`

```
import readXlsxFile from "read-excel-file";

export default function MyExcelImport() {
    const handleFileChange = (event) => {
        console.log("handleFileChange", event);
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log("file", file);
    
        readXlsxFile(file).then((rows) => {
            // `rows` is an array of rows
            // each row being an array of cells.
            console.log("rows", rows);
        });
    };
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e)} />
        </div>
    );
}
```